# Deploying django(windows) with apache(on unix)

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, waitress

I know it might be a bad design but since we are **developing the django website on our laptops which runs Win7**, I thought it would be better to run django on a Windows platform only in production.

(**Laptop is not powerful enough to run a Unix VM** inside and our Unix team doesn't provide any Unix server with UI access (Only Putty) so using an IDE is impossible on Unix.)

I have deployed django with gunicorn and nginx on a Linux server very easily, but this time **I have to deploy django on a Windows server with Apache on another Unix server** (I know it sucks).

Our middleware team is asking(forcing) to run django components on a separate server so that they can manage their Apache (on Unix) instance comfortably. As far as I understand, Apache and django should reside on the same server for mod_wsgi to work.

**Is this possible to keep Apache on a Unix machine and make a django website run from a Windows machine?**

If not, what are the **best possible solutions** in my case? (Switch django on Unix? Use waitress on Django windows? Do not separate Apache and Django? etc.)

Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deploying on IIS instead, as it is the native Web Server on Windows Servers.

Checkout the `django-windowsauth` package, you can use it to deploy your project to IIS using few simple commands. https://github.com/danyi1212/django-windowsauth.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing in my modest point of view is to create a unix docker image of your project

Comment: thanks! I ended up running django app using waitress as windows service. Apache could act as a reverse proxy to waitress.

Comment: Congratulations, I'm happy to hear about that. I never used Waitress. I'll take a look

Comment: Sure, its a wsgi server for windows, similar to gunicorn on unix.